# Inserting ckeditor table in internet explorer fails

Tags: ckeditor

There is an issue while inserting table in CKEditor in internet explorer.

When I insert a table with more then one row it shows like there is only one row in it. When I apply height through firebug using jQuery it works fine but from code function triggers it is not working.

`$("[id*='cke_Description'] iframe").contents().find('table').css('height', '20px');`

Comment: Do you get any console errors? The code you gave us displays a very strange way of setting a table height. Why do it this way? What are you trying to do ultimately? I'm almost 100% certain that there is a better way to do this than using triggers... However, the "shows like there is only one row in it" is a major problem. Can you show us more of your code and maybe a screenshot? As it is, it's *very* hard to know what's going on.

Comment: @Nenotlep no i didn't get any console errors. here is the function that i use for resize table.
$("#body-container").live('mouseover', function () {
    if ($.browser.msie == true) {
         $("[id*='cke_Description_'] iframe").contents().find('table').css('height', '20px');
        $("[id*='cke_Description_'] iframe").contents().find('table').find('tr').css('height', '20px');
    }
});

Comment: Why do you do that? This seems like a really strange thing to do and I can't understand what purpose could this possibly serve.

Comment: Also, what version of CKEditor do you have and what version of IE do you use?